# occassional Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, bower

I'm working on an angular app, and it works completely fine on computer#1, and when I've cloned the git repo on computer#2 and performed my `npm install`, `bower install`, and `grunt bower-install`, things fail to load.

After googling around, many have cited that this is a common side effect of ng-route not being included.

Upon page load, 'view source' appears to show that ng-route was successfully included:

```
<!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-codemirror/ui-codemirror.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And my app.js file definitely is asking for `ngRoute`:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'chart.js',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ui.codemirror'
])
```

and my routes are defined this way:

```
$routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard',
  controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
})
```

Then I've checked that those dependencies have in fact loaded:

[image]

^-- which appears to be "yes" they have loaded. I've clicked through them to make sure the responses are actually the correct javascript content. Each contains the correct content.

In terms of version of the `angular-route.js` resource,

- the working site uses route v1.3.14
- the not-working site uses route v1.3.15

The error message in the console doesn't appear to have anything useful in it in terms of identifying why this is happening. How do I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your answer got solved I got similar issue now,

I got this issue because I have different versions of `angular.min.js` and `angular-route.js`

I have used 1.2.0 of Angular and 1.3.5 of angular-route.js and that caused the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you properly have the following components into your bower dir ?

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Or if you have any HTML issue into Network regarding the downloading of the package ?

Your error looks like the ngRoute module is not loaded and when trying to use the provider, generates this issue.

Comment: can you compare the version of the routing service taht you used on computer1 with the version that you have ? 
If there is a difference into version, force the bower version with ^X.X.X into bower json file